# Understanding $T(x)=3x\pmod 1$

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

> Let $T:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be such that $T(x)=3x\pmod{1}$ which is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel on $[0,1]$, which we denote by $\mathscr{B}_{[0,1]}$.
>   Prove that Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ is T-invariant.

I know that if $[a,b]\in T(x)$ then as the measure is invariant $T^{-1}([a,b])=I_1\cup I_2\cup I_3$. However I do not know how to determine the intervals.

**Question:**
Can someone explain me how should I work with the inverse of $T$?

Comment: How come "as the measure is invariant" has anything to do with having a preimage the union of $3$ intervals?

Comment: Because it the Lebesgue measure of the union of those three intervals which equals the whole interval.

Comment: Well, for example, $T^{-1}([0,\frac15])=[0,\frac1{15}]\cup[\frac13,\frac25]\cup[\frac23,\frac{11}{15}]$. Where is the mystery?

Comment: @Did The mystery is the logical link between the two. There is no apparent (at least for me) link between the degree of a map on the circle and the fact the measure is invariant. It's easy to exhibit continuous maps of the circle, preserving (say) Lebesgue measure, such that the preimage of an interval is not the union of three intervals. Or maps of degree 3 that do not preserve Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A broad hint rather than a solution**:

What things map to, say, $x = .30$ under $T$? Well, there's $u_1 = 0.1$, and then there's $u_2 = u_1 + \frac{1}{3}$, and there's $u_3 = u_1 + \frac{2}{3}$

More generally,
$$
T^{-1} ([a, b]) =  [\frac{a}{3}, \frac{b}{3}] \cup [\frac{a+1}{3}, \frac{b+1}{3}] \cup [\frac{a+2}{3}, \frac{b+2}{3}].
$$

With that in mind, perhaps you can make some progress.

Comment: Is it not $0.1$ instead of $0.0.1$?

Comment: So much for my ability to put a decimal in the right place! Thanks for noticing. Now fixed.